# Show the space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ with the 2 norm for functions is not complete.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I know that I need to find a a Cauchy sequence of functions such that the sequence does not converege, in order to show the space is not complete.

I have tried different functions but always get a nasty integral, is there a straightforward counterexample.

Comment: Hint: A step-function is not continuous, but by slanting the steps by an $\epsilon$ you get a sequence of continuous functions that converges (and thus Cauchy) in $L^2$-norm as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, but does not have a continuous limit.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Let $f_n(x)=0$ for $x <\frac 1 2$, $1$ for $x >\frac  1 2+\frac 1 n$ and $f_n(x)=n(x-\frac 1  2)$ for $\frac 1  2 \leq x \leq \frac 1  2+\frac 1  n$. Then $(f_n)$ is  a Cauchy sequence which does not converge to a continuous function in the norm.

Comment: When showing this is cauchy with the 2 norm doesn't this give us a long integral again

Comment: No. If $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere and $f_n$ is bounded then $\int |f_n(x)-f(x)|^{2}dx \to 0$. There is need to evaluate the integral.  @DylanDijk

Comment: Oh okay, we just use pointwise convergence of $f_n$ to show the sequence of functions is Cauchy.

Comment: Actually the function you constructed does converge w.r.t to the norm

Comment: @DylanDijk Not to an element of $C[0,1]$. That is the whole point of this construction.

Comment: Ok, so we know that this series of functions converges to a function that is continuous. And therefore it is a cauchy sequence which does not converge to function in this space. Therefore the space of continuous functions in [0,1] is not complete with the 2 norm.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f_n\in C[0,1]$ which take value 0 on $[0,\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}]$ , value 1 on $[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}]$ and takes linear on $[\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}]$. Show its limit is the characteristic function $\chi_{[\frac{1}{2},1]}$, which not continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Let $C$ be the space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$. It's well-known that $C$ is complete with the sup-norm.

Let's define $T$ as
$$T:(C, \lVert . \rVert_\infty) \to (C, \lVert . \rVert_2), Tf=f$$
i.e. $T$ is the identity operator. $T$ is continuous, because
$$\lVert f \rVert_\infty = 1 \implies |f| \leqslant 1 \implies |f|^2 \leqslant 1 \implies \lVert f \rVert_2 \leqslant 1$$
If $C$ were complete with the $2$-norm, the Banach's linear homeomorphism theorem would guarantee that $T^{-1}$ is continuous. But if we define $f_n$ as $f_n(x)=x^n$, then we have that $\lVert f_n \rVert_\infty = 1$, while $\lVert f_n \rVert_2 \to 0$, which implies that $T^{-1}$ is not continuous, so $C$ can't be complete with the $2$-norm.